# Avoid long conditional statements to call functions with the same arguments but different names?

Tags: python

I have a number of functions that have the same arguments but do slightly different computations under the hood. As a contrived example:

```py
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b

def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    return a / b
```

I then find myself having to call these functions in a separate program, e.g.:

```py
def myfunc(a, b, op):
    if op == "add": return add(a, b)
    if op == "multiply": return multiply(a, b)
    # etc etc
```

What are some Pythonic ways to avoid this? The only option I can think of is to define a more generic function like this:

```py
def do_something(a, b, op):
    if op == "add": return add(a, b)
    if op == "multiply": return multiply(a, b)
    # etc etc

def myfunc(a, b, op): 
    return do_something(a, b, op)
```

which is cleaner for `myfunc` but still has the drawback of the long conditional statements.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `do_something` more generic than the original `myfunc`? They're identical.

Comment: @Barmar For my case, putting all the fluff into `do_something` simply means that it isn't exposed in my `myfunc` which can simply look better.

Comment: I don't understand. It seems like all you've done is rename `myfunc` to `do_something`, and then defined a new `myfunc` that calls it.

Comment: @Barmar You could put `do_something` in a separate file and have `my_func` in a `main` file

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary.

```
operations = {"add": add, "multiply": multiply, "divide": divide}
def myfunc(a, b, op):
    return operations[op](a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.10, you know have the ability to use match case!

```py
match op:
    case "add":
        etc
    case "multiply":
        etc
    etc
```

Another option is to use a dictionary, which may look cleaner, but is much harder to debug.

```py
choices = {"add": add, "multiply": multiply, ...}
```

Then, simply call
`choices[op](a,b)`
and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

what about passing the function instead of a string?

```py
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b

def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    return a / b

def myfunc(a, b, op):
    return op(a, b)

print(myfunc(2, 3, add))
print(myfunc(2, 3, multiply))
print(myfunc(2, 3, divide))
```

if you prefer to pass operation as string you can use `eval`:

```py
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b

def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    return a / b

def myfunc(a, b, op):
    return eval(op)(a, b)

print(myfunc(2, 3, "add"))
print(myfunc(2, 3, "multiply"))
print(myfunc(2, 3, "divide"))
```